# I am getting an Error when I save to a String List. Flutter/Dart

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Printing my List is fine in the terminal but when I want to save it to the Cache, I am getting this error :

```
Error: The argument type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<String>'.
```

The Error is pointing towards :

```
await WriteCache.setListString(key: 'cache4', value: incidentList);
```

This is my code :

```
onTap: () async {
                  var newMessage = await (ReadCache.getString(key: 'cache1'));

                  var response = await http.get(
                    Uri.parse(
                        'http://192.168.1.8:8080/HongLeong/MENU_REQUEST.do?_dc=1658076505340&reset_context=1&table_id=25510&id_MenuAction=3&path=%3Cp%20class%3D%22x-window-header-path%22%3ELoss%20Event%3C%2Fp%3E&ViewType=MENU_REQUEST&gui_open_popup=1&id_Window=17&activeWindowId=mw_17&noOrigUserDate=true&LocalDate=20220718&LocalTime=00482500&TimeZone=Asia%2FShanghai&UserDate=0&UserTime=0&server_name=OPRISK_DATACOLLECTOR&key_id_list=&cell_context_id=0&id_Desktop=100252&operation_key=1000184&operation_sub_num=-1&is_json=1&is_popup=0&is_search_window=0&ccsfw_conf_by_user=0&is_batch=0&previousToken=1658069547560&historyToken=1658076505339&historyUrl=1'),
                    headers: {HttpHeaders.cookieHeader: newMessage},
                  );

                  LossEventResponseModel lossEventResponseModel =
                  LossEventResponseModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));

                  final listNode = lossEventResponseModel.response.genericListAnswer.listNode;

                  List<Map<String, dynamic>> incidentList = [
                    for (final json in listNode.map((x) => x.toJson()))
                      {
                        'Code': json['field'][0]['field_value'],
                        'Description': json['field'][1]['field_value'],
                        'Organisation Unit': json['field'][46]['field_value'],
                        'Date Reported': json['field'][18]['field_value'],
                      }
                  ];

                  await WriteCache.setListString(key: 'cache4', value: incidentList);
                  print(incidentList);



                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const LossEvent()));
                },
```

This is what I am printing :

```
 [{Code: LE-0000000002, Description: test_01, Organisation Unit: 01_01_04_01_SA - Shah Alam, Date Reported: 18/09/2020}, {Code: LE-0000000003, Description: Transactions not reported (intentional), Organisation Unit: 01_01_04_01_HQ - Menara Hong Leong, Damansara City, Date Reported: 03/02/2018},and so on.....
```

I would really love to display it as :

```
Code: LE-0000000002,
Description: test_01,
Organisation Unit: 01_01_04_01_SA - Shah Alam,
Date Reported: Date Reported: 18/09/2020,
```

but the error is stopping me from doing so.
Any advice on fixing my code would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Storing the List

`WriteCache.setListString()` expects a value of type `List<String>`, but incidentList has the type `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`.

Instead, consider encoding your list as JSON, and store it using `WriteCache.setString()`:

```dart
// Top of file:
import 'dart:convert';

// In onTap:
final incidentListJson = jsonEncode(incidentList);
await WriteCache.setString(key: 'cache4', value: incidentListJson);
```

**Note:** When reading the cache, you will also need to use `decodeJson` to convert the JSON string back into a list:

```dart
final incidentListJson = await ReadCache.getString(key: 'cache4');
final List incidentList = jsonDecode(incidentListJson);
```

### Formatting the List

If you'd like the list to be formatted in the way you showed, you can define a function for that:

```dart
String formatIncidentList(List<Map<String, dynamic>> list) {
  return list.map(
    (incident) => incident.entries.map(
      (entry) => "${entry.key}: ${entry.value},"
    ),
  ).join("\n");
}

// Usage:
print(formatIncidentsList(incidentList));
```

Comment: it works!! thanks, how do I put this in a List Tile? E.g. The listView builder reads the cache and the list tile has the information in the format wanted. I'm even more confused in this part

Comment: I'm happy to help, but you might want to ask a new question, or add some more code with explanation about what you're trying achieve

Comment: I've posted another question regarding your code, maybe you could share your insight.

Answer (score 1):

You can check `setListString` takes key and list of String

```dart
 static Future setListString(
      {required String key, required List<String> value})
```

But you are trying to put list of map

`List<Map<String, dynamic>> incidentList`

You can do something like

```dart
final List<String>values =  [];

for(final item in incidentList){
values.addAll(item.values.map((e) => e.toString()));
}
await WriteCache.setListString(key: 'cache4', value: values);
```

More about [cache_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/cache_manager/versions/1.0.0+3)

Comment: this works great too! Thanks. but its displaying my elements separately in my List View.

Comment: also how do I send the keys aswell? so that I can reference them?